# How are Rust crates (e.g. num_cpus) implemented?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I was wondering how are Rust crates are implemented.

For example, there is a crate named `num_cpus`. This crate has this basic method `num_cpus::get()` which tells number of CPUs in your computer.

My questions:

- How is the method `num_cpus::get()` implemented (is it done using another language?)
- Can the same result be achieved with plain Rust code without using any crates?

Answer (score 3):

... in Rust.  There's no reason to believe it'd be anything else.

You can also check this by just *looking at the source code*, easily done by:

1. [Search `crates.io` for "num_cpus".](https://crates.io/search?q=num_cpus).
2. [Select the `num_cpus` crate.](https://crates.io/crates/num_cpus)
3. [Select "Repository" for the source code.](https://github.com/seanmonstar/num_cpus)
4. [Open the only `.rs` source file in the repository, `src/lib.rs`.](https://github.com/seanmonstar/num_cpus/blob/master/src/lib.rs)

Comment: Wow, team RUST <3